# Delete many columns with null

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, null, where-clause

I have a table with 34 columns.
First 4 columns form the primary key (thus they do not have nulls in them) and rest 30 columns have data in them also nulls.
I wish to delete all the rows where the other 30 columns are null.
A way would be -

```
delete from my_table
where column_30 is null
and columns_29 is null
and column_28 is null
and column_27 is null
...
...
...
```

Is there any easy way to do this without mentioning all 30 column names?

Comment: Not really. Around about now you should be asking yourself whether this table is *correctly designed* at all. Not possible to say of course when you've just given us vague column names but I'm suspicious of any table with a large number of columns especially when all non-PK columns can all be null.

Comment: It is an input table and is a direct dump from csv file so it has no constraints and checks

Answer (score 2):

No, that's impossible. You could shorten the code a bit but pay a [penalty in sargability](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/162024/is-coalesce-sargable-now) - using [`coalesce`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

```
delete from my_table
where coalesce(column_30, column_29, column_28.....) is null
```

As Damien wrote in his comment - this will only work if all columns are of compatible types, meaning SQL Server can implicitly convert between them.

Comment: I think this assumes all of these columns are of compatible types. If one of them is say and `int` and the rest are `varchar(something)` then this query will choke on the first (non-null obviously) string that cannot be converted to `int`.

Answer (score 1):

`coalesce` receives a list of expressions and returns the first not-null one, or null if they all are, so you can use it as some sort of a shorthand:

```
DELETE FROM mytable
WHERE  COALESCE(column_30, column_29, column_28, ...) IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach of doing it. (Assuming that the datatype of all the columns is same)

```
delete t 
from   my_table t 
where  (select top 1 1 as col 
        from   (values  (T.column_30), 
                        (T.columns_29), 
                        (T.columns_28 ), 
                        (T.columns_27 )) v(x) 
        where  x is null) = 1
```